# How is this formula derived?

Tags: geometry

[image]

how is the formula derived though from this we can calculate the volume?

Answer (score 2):

$r(z)$ is just linear interpolation between the points $(0,R_1)$ and $(h,R_2)$.

To see this, suppose $r(z) = mz+b$. You require $r(0)=R_1$ and $r(h)=R_2$. The first condition gives you
$$R_1=r(0)=m\cdot0+b = b$$
so
$$r(z)=mz+R_1$$
The second condition gives you $$R_2=r(h)=mh+R_1$$
so
$$m=\frac{R_2-R_1}{h}$$
Therefore
$$r(z) = \left(\frac{R_2-R_1}{h}\right)z + R_1 = \boxed{R_1 + (R_2-R_1)\frac zh}$$ as desired.

**Addendum:** Generally speaking, if you want $y$ to change linearly $c$ to $d$ as $x$ varies from $a$ to $b$, then you can write
$$y(x) = c + \left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)(d-c)$$
In this form, you can see explicitly that when $x=a$ you have $y=c$, and when $x=b$ you have $y=d$, and the function is linear. You can rearrange this in various ways, but I always like this form.

In your case, $a=0$, $b=h$, $c=R_1$, and $d=R_2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is found by direct integration:

slope of slant generator

$$ m=\frac{R_1-R_2}{h}$$

Stating at larger end slope is $<0$

( although I prefer to proceed from top to bottom circles)

$$ r = R_1 - m z =  R_1 - \frac{R_1-R_2}{h} z  $$

Volume
$$ V = \pi \int_{R_2/m}^{R_1/m}(x\cdot m)^2 dx $$